# Need help to connect the awt app with MS Access database

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, odbc, awt

I have developed an awt program and now i am trying to connect it to the MS Access Database using ODBC bridge.

Here is the code :-

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.*;

class MyClass
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
     Project prj=new Project();
  }
}

class Project
{
Statement s;
Connection con;
String s1,s2;
TextField t1,t2;
Button b1,b2;

Project()
{
Frame f=new Frame("Registration");
f.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
f.setSize(400,400);

Panel p1=new Panel();
p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
t1=new TextField(15);
t2=new TextField(30);
p1.add(new Label("Roll :"));
p1.add(t1);
p1.add(new Label("Name :"));
p1.add(t2);
f.add(p1);

Panel p2=new Panel();
p2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
s1=t1.getText();
s2=t2.getText();

try{
   try
      {Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
      }
       catch(Exception e){}
   con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:testdb");
   s=con.createStatement();
   }catch(SQLException e){System.out.println("Error in connecting to database"); }

b1=new Button("Submit");
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  try{
 s.executeUpdate("insert into college(Roll,Names) values("+Integer.parseInt(s1)+","+s2+")");        
  }catch(SQLException se){
  System.out.println(se);}
}});
b2=new Button("Quit");
 b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){System.exit(0);
   }});
p2.add(b1);
p2.add(b2);
f.add(p2);
f.pack();

    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

When i use the following statement in the actionListener

```
 s.executeUpdate("insert into college(Roll,Names) values (555,'Naveen')");
```

the values are inserted into the database.But when i use the statement,which now takes values from the textfield,

```
s.executeUpdate("insert into college(Roll,Names) values ("+Integer.parseInt(s1)+","+s2+")");
```

as used in the above code,i am getting the exception ,which i catch using the try catch block.

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.
```

There is definitely something wrong in the sql statement .Where am i wrong???

Comment: your s1 is not a valid int on this line Integer.parseInt(s1), thus NFE..

Comment: @chaitanya10 :s1 contains the integer value obtained from textfield which is passed as string,so i have used Integer.parseInt(s1) to convert that string value back to  int.What is the problem??

Comment: Please see the edited question,as I have resolved that previous exception.

Comment: what exception are you getting now? SQLException??

Comment: The Exception now is :

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your s2 inside inside single quotes('') as you were doing in your first insert statement.

try this:

```
s.executeUpdate("insert into college(Roll,Names) values ("+Integer.parseInt(s1)+",'"+s2+"')");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the value whats coming inside s1 ,It must not be valid String to parse into int